# Apache server: Alternative to editing hosts file on user's Windows 7/10

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, hosts-file

I have an Apache server running MyWebsite. This server is either on VirtualBox or on a standalone box that I run an Ethernet cable to. Until recently I had always accessed it by typing the ip address into the browser. Now I have given it a domain name myIP.myWebsite.com and am trying to access it by typing that domain name into my browser. If I edit the hosts file on my PC to have a line

```
myIP myIP.myWebsite.com
```

then this will work and my website will load by entering either the IP address or the domain name. (If I enter the IP address it will redirect to the domain name.)

The problem is that my IP address can change and each time the hosts file needs to be edited. That is not a problem for me, but I have users without admin rights who can't edit that file. I also heard that editing the hosts file won't let me see the site on every PC because the virus protection someone has could prevent the PC using the hosts file (or something along that line).

I would like an alternative to editing the hosts file. As it stands, if I do not edit the hosts file and try to get to the website, Internet Explorer will just display "The page can't be displayed".

What could be a clue is that even when I delete all the memory for the browser, the IP address will still redirect to myIP.myWebsite.com. This makes me think that it gets to the server but can't show the page?

If you need any more information, please let me know. In case it wasn't clear my question is: **What is an alternative to editing the hosts file on the users PC?**

Comment: "What is an alternative to editing the hosts file on the users PC?" - Use a Dynamic DNS provider to continuously update the ip address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an DNS server , if you have admin right on your server inside virtualbox ?

1- On your your VirtualBox system install and configure dnsmasq

> http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html

2- Add a type A DNS entry into dnsmasq conf: address=\www.myWebsite.lan
\10.25.36.2\

3- Tell your client to use this DNS server. ex for windows client:

> Open control pannel : cmd /c "control /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter"
>
> Click on Left : Network interface parameters modification
>
> Choose your network card and double click on this
>
> Click Property
>
> Double Click on TCP/Ipv4
>
> Check Use DNS server...
>
> In first field put your VirtualBox dnsmasq server ip address
>
> Validate all

For the other DNS requests... probably, the most simply solution is to upstream all other domains with dnsmasq and with your 'default' dns server ... I you want more informations about this ,let me know.

> Now all dns requests are resolved by this DNS server...

**NOTE**: This solution is for IPv4 only and must be repeated for IPv6